# Calculate loan payoff date

Tags: javascript, math, calculator, calc

I have several inputs from the user like..
Original Balance, Current Balance, Interest Rate, Term (Years), Payment Amount, Monthly Income, Living Expenses, Start Date etc.
I don't have a commerce background and google couldn't help me.
I only want to calculate approx payoff date. Can I have such formula in simple math terms so I can convert that into javascript function?

```
function calcme() {
    var originalBal = Number(document.getElementById("calc-ob").value);
    var currentBal = Number(document.getElementById("calc-cb").value);
    var interestRate = Number(document.getElementById("calc-ir").value);
    var term = Number(document.getElementById("calc-term").value);
    var monthlyPayment = Number(document.getElementById("calc-pa").value);
    var totalIncome = Number(document.getElementById("calc-toi").value);
    var livingExpense = Number(document.getElementById("calc-le").value);

    var monthlyInterest = (interestRate/100)/12

    var paydate = currentBal - ( totalIncome/ 2 ) + livingExpense - monthlyPayment + monthlyInterest

    document.getElementById('calc-date').value = paydate
}
```

I tried what I wrote above and it works. It's just that I need a correct formula. I need it to return date on which loan will end(i.e. it will paid off) in date format.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while the ultimate goal is to do this programmatically, the question is really about a basic *mathematics* problem.

Comment: So I can post programming problem but not a mathematical problem? It still needs your logic to understand the calculation.

Comment: There's some answers on the money and personal finance stack exchange https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48775/what-is-the-formula-for-loan-payoff-with-daily-compounded-interest-and-monthly-p this should help you.

Comment: You can have a mathematical problem, that's why there is a math-tag. Nevertheless, if you press the "Ask Question" it states "Is your question about programming? We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research." for a reason. To be honest, I do not think that there is zero effort in your post, but try to summarize (better than linking to an external page) your research. Still, it is not really a programming question and the suggestion of "money and personal finance stack exchange "might be the best option. Good luck.

Comment: BTW the if `interest` is the yearly interest it should be done via `(...)^(1/12)` and not by (.../12). Cheers.

Comment: Two JavaScript suggestions: (1) Pay more attention to naming of functions and variables.  "calcMe" is not a good name for a function. Names should make clear what the function is doing or what the variable means.  (2) Move DOM manipulations out of your function and pass them in as parameters.  It'll be easier to unit test your function and prove its correctness that way.